# CodeIgniter 4 redirect()->to() not working on IE

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-4

I am getting error from IE when I redirect to "dashboard" controller after settings session values in "login" function ( `return redirect()->to(base_url('dashboard'));`). I have this working on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera.

I am using `public $sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler';` for session storage. this works well with other borwsers.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class User extends BaseController
{
    public function login()
    {
        $data = [];

        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {

            $rules = [
                'email' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email',
                'password' => 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]|validateUser[email,password]',
            ];

            $errors = [
                'password' => [
                    'validateUser' => "Email or Password don't match",
                ],
            ];

            if (!$this->validate($rules, $errors)) {

                return view('login', [
                    "validation" => $this->validator,
                ]);

            } else {
                $model = new UserModel();

                $user = $model->where('email', $this->request->getVar('email'))
                    ->first();

                // Stroing session values
                $this->setUserSession($user);
                // Redirecting to dashboard after login
                return redirect()->to(base_url('dashboard'));

            }
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    private function setUserSession($user)
    {
        $data = [
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'phone_no' => $user['phone_no'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            'isLoggedIn' => true,
        ];

        session()->set($data);
        return true;
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $data = [];

        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            //let's do the validation here
            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                'phone_no' => 'required|min_length[9]|max_length[20]',
                'email' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_users.email]',
                'password' => 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]',
                'password_confirm' => 'matches[password]',
            ];

            if (!$this->validate($rules)) {

                return view('register', [
                    "validation" => $this->validator,
                ]);
            } else {
                $model = new UserModel();

                $newData = [
                    'name' => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                    'phone_no' => $this->request->getVar('phone_no'),
                    'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                    'password' => $this->request->getVar('password'),
                ];
                $model->save($newData);
                $session = session();
                $session->setFlashdata('success', 'Successful Registration');
                return redirect()->to(base_url('login'));
            }
        }
        return view('register');
    }

    public function profile()
    {

        $data = [];
        $model = new UserModel();

        $data['user'] = $model->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();
        return view('profile', $data);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session()->destroy();
        return redirect()->to('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: IE? which version, please

Comment: @Vickel Its IE 11

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter4 has its "user agent class" this should help you to be able to validate if you are using IE, I share the documentation and I hope it helps you.
You can validate using that class and redirect with another method.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html